# Estimate a value with square roots squared without calculating

Tags: algebra-precalculus

*If $n$ is a natural number and $n<(6+\sqrt{29})^2<n+1$, find the value of $n$.*

---

This problem is, of course, very easy to solve with a calculator. But I am looking for a solution that does **NOT** need to find the value of $(6+\sqrt{29})^2$. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: This is an irrational number. How many decimals ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without a calculator,

$$(6+\sqrt{29})^2=36+12\sqrt{29}+29=65+12\sqrt{29}=125+12(\sqrt{29}-5)=125+{48\over\sqrt{29}+5}$$

Now $5\lt\sqrt{29}\lt6$ implies

$$4\lt{48\over11}\lt{48\over\sqrt{29}+5}\lt{48\over10}\lt5$$

Thus

$$129\lt(6+\sqrt{29})^2\lt130$$

Comment: Nice proof (+1)

Comment: Why make the denominator $\sqrt{29}+5$? Is +4 or +3 fine?

Comment: @Cyh1368, $\sqrt{29}+5$ is the "conjugate" to $\sqrt{29}-5$, i.e., $(\sqrt{25}+5)(\sqrt{29}-5)=29-25=4$.

Comment: @BarryCipra But what if we used $\sqrt{29}-4$ in the first place? Then can't we just ues $\sqrt{29}+4$ as the conjugate?

Comment: @Cyh1368, ah, I see what you're getting at: How did I know to turn $65+12\sqrt{29}$ into $125+12(\sqrt{29}-5)$ rather than $113+12(\sqrt{29}-4)$? The idea is to use a $12(\sqrt{29}-a)$ that makes the numerator, $12(29-a^2)$, as small as possible.

Answer (score 3):

Expand the expression to get $36+12\sqrt{29}+29=65+\sqrt{4176}$. Now you only need to find the integer $m$ such that $m<\sqrt{4176}<m+1$, i.e. $m^2<4176<(m+1)^2$.

Comment: It's a simple solution, but still need some time to figure out $\sqrt{4176}$

Comment: @Cyh1368: Yes, you are right -- I prefer the other solutions to mine. (But as every programmer knows, $64^2=4096$.)

Comment: (+1), and $65^2 = (6\times 7)\times 100+25=4225$ is a well-known trick too.

Answer (score 2):

$5<\sqrt{29}<6$, so $0<6-\sqrt{29}<1$, so $0<(6-\sqrt{29})^2<1$.

$(6+\sqrt{29})^2<(6+\sqrt{29})^2+(6-\sqrt{29})^2<(6+\sqrt{29})^2+1$.

But $(6+\sqrt{29})^2+(6-\sqrt{29})^2=36+12\sqrt{29}+29+36-12\sqrt{29}+29=130$.

So $(6+\sqrt{29})^2<130<(6+\sqrt{29})^2+1$.

So $129<(6+\sqrt{29})^2<130$.

Answer (score 1):

Use the difference of two squares to get:

$$6+\sqrt{29} = \frac{(6+\sqrt{29})(6-\sqrt{29})}{6-\sqrt{29}} = \frac{7}{6 - \sqrt{29}}$$

and so:

$$n<\frac{49}{(6-\sqrt{29})^2}<n+1 \Rightarrow \frac{1}{n+1} < \frac{(6 - \sqrt{29})^2}{49} < \frac{1}{n}.$$

Adding $49$ times this inequality with the original gives:

$$n + \frac{49}{n+1} < (6 + \sqrt{29})^2 + (6 - \sqrt{29})^2 < n+1 + \frac{49}{n}$$
$$\Rightarrow n + \frac{49}{n+1} < 130 < n+1 + \frac{49}{n}$$

From the right-hand side, the minimum value of $n$ which satisfies the inequality is $129$. But from the left-hand side, $n$ cannot be $130$ or greater. Therefore $n = 129$ which is the unique solution.

Comment: Note that solving this inequality by expanding and using the quadratic formula would be horrendous.